# SOAP security negotiation with 'http://hostname/adfs/services/policystoretransfer' failed

Tags: adfs

I am trying to add a second server to an existing ADFS deployment, but I am unable to do that because I received the below message:

"SOAP security negotiation with 'http://hostname/adfs/services/policystoretransfer' for target 'http://hostname/adfs/services/policystoretransfer' failed. See inner exception for more details."

Any help?